# problema no ajaxSucess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Olá, estou com uma dificuldade em executar um script depois de uma chamada em ajax.

**O que eu fiz até o momento?**

Bom, vou explicar: Eu tenho um botão com 2 ações, porém, necessito que uma ação ocorra antes da outra,  ***as duas não estão juntas***.

Já consegui fazer o script, mas há um erro, **toda vez que há essa requisição do ajax, o script executa a quantidade de requisições que foram feitas**, ou seja, é como se tivesse um contador.

**Onde necessito de ajuda?**

Preciso que a cada requisição feita, não haja esse tipo de evento ('contador'), que ele execute somente um vez, independente de quantas requisições foram feitas!

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.url === "somefile.php") {
    alert('hi');
  }
});
```

Comment: Esse código `$(document).ajaxSuccess()` corre só uma vez ou aparece em partes do código que se repetem?

Comment: Então, esse código só tem uma vez, mas a cada vez que essa minha url é executada ele faz algo, ou seja, se eu clicar em um botão duas vezes, no primeiro ele irá executar o script uma vez, agora na segunda vez, ele irá executar o mesmo script duas vezes, e assim por diante.

Comment: `ajaxSuccess` é para interceptar TODAS as requisições Ajax da página. É isso mesmo que você quer? Mostre o código onde você faz a requisição, acho que é lá que você deveria trabalhar.

Comment: Isso mesmo, vamos dizer assim, qualquer requisição que haja, eu quero verificar a url, se for x url, então vou executar algo.
O problema está que ele começar a executar x vezes o script a partir das requisições feitas com sucesso. Quero se seja executada somente a última.

Comment: Será que o Ajax está a ser adicionado repetido algures no teu código? E assim é o proprio ajax que é chamado vezes a mais e não erro com o `.ajaxSuccess`.

Comment: Veja o que acontece, eu coloque para o script aceitar 2 url diferentes...

https://snag.gy/oN1W7a

Comment: Hmm essa imagem confirma o que estou a pensar. Cada vez vez há mais um post. Sem ver o teu código fica dificil ajudar mais.